# Show correct content type with custom display item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, display-template

I am using the following code in a custom display template for my search results to show the correct content type of an item:

```
_#=ctx.CurrentItem.ContentType=#_
```

The good part is that it returns the correct content type (e.g. Sales docs), but it returns also the MIME type: application/word. How to only show the content type text without the MIME type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this with the following (dirty) JavaScript code:

```
        var CT_s1 = ctx.CurrentItem.ContentType;
        var CT_s2 = CT_s1.replace(/\s/g, '_');  
        var CT_s3 = CT_s2.lastIndexOf('__');
        var CT_s4 = CT_s2.substring(CT_s3 +1);
        var CT_label = CT_s4.replace(/_/g, ' ');
```

And in the item display template:

```
<span>_#=CT_label=#_</span>
```